# Why do I get JavaScript undefined property in Observable but not in HTML?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am [trying to use Mike Bostock's 'Observable' to re-create a simple HTML webpage](https://beta.observablehq.com/@aaronkyle/learning-javascript-and-observable-by-converting-fiddle), but I am encountering  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeFormat' of undefined`  in reference to the line of code that draws the chart, namely:

`d3.select('#events').data([repositoriesData]).call(chart);`

As [visible in my notebook](https://beta.observablehq.com/@aaronkyle/learning-javascript-and-observable-by-converting-fiddle), the error points to the `.call(chart)` parameter.

**Can anyone help me why I get this error in [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/@aaronkyle/learning-javascript-and-observable-by-converting-fiddle) when the script works just fine in HTML?  And how can I fix it?**

As evinced by [Alpesh Jikadra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2857556/alpesh-jikadra) comment and jsFiddle (below), the JavaScript function works just fine when embedded in a standard HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--https://jsfiddle.net/6rqxusw5/9/-->
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/event-drops/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Event Drops</h1>
    <div id="events"></div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.13.0/build/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/event-drops/dist/index.js"></script>

  <script>
  const repositoriesData = [{
      name: "intake",
        data: [
            { date: new Date('03/02/2018 6:55:11 PM') },
          { date: new Date('03/02/2018 10:56:11 PM') },
          { date: new Date('03/03/2018 6:57:11 AM') },
        ]
  }, {
      name: "eligibility",
        data: [
            { date: new Date('03/03/2018 6:58:09 PM') },
            { date: new Date('03/03/2018 11:58:09 PM') },        ]
  }, {
    name: "assessment",
        data: [
            { date: new Date('03/04/2018 6:59:09 PM') }
        ]
  }, {
    name: "dispute resolution",
        data: [
            { date: new Date('03/05/2018 7:01:09 AM') }
        ]
  }, {
    name: "compliance",
        data: [
            { date: new Date('03/05/2018 7:05:09 PM') }
        ]
  }, {
      name: "closure",
        data: [
          { date: new Date('03/05/2018 11:12:07 PM') }
        ]
  }];

  var chart = eventDrops({
      range: {
          start: new Date('03/01/2018 6:55:11 PM'),
          end: new Date('03/06/2018 7:15:11 PM')
        },
        drop: {
            date: d => d.date,
        },
  });

  d3.select('#events').data([repositoriesData]).call(chart);
  </script>


</html>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong in terms of the organization of the code in Observable and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is your question ? https://jsfiddle.net/4mqx3j8k/ this is working fine

Comment: The question is what I am doing wrong in [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/@aaronkyle/learning-javascript-and-observable-by-converting-fiddle), where the script gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeFormat' of undefined`.

Comment: Where do you get error, at which line ? correct your question to show what you are asking

Comment: @Alpesh-Jikadra, thank you for your help. I have attempted to re-phase the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: You are apparently using some beta notebook software that does not have a tag here, meaning you are unlikely to get help. Your best bet is probably to try to contact the author of the software.

Comment: Thank you, Jared.  I was hoping the issue was not with the software but instead with the limits of my understanding about different JavaScript elements (such as those responsible for rendering a chart) and how they loaded into a web page.

Comment: Look at `eventDrops`. It has just a `ƒ (t)` on top of it. That's not what should appear (have a look at D3 just above it, for comparison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided by [Tom MacWright](https://macwright.org/) in the [Observable help forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/why-do-i-get-javascript-undefined-property-in-observable-but-not-in-html/587/2), where I raised the question after being prompted by [Jared Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith):

> The event-drops module expects d3 to be just ‘hanging around’ on the window object. This isn’t ideal: modules should really declare their dependencies and load them with AMD, but anyway - it’s not a dealbreaker. I added a cell that sets `window.d3 = d3` and that makes event-drops happy. This was the issue that complained about `timeFormat` - it expected `d3.timeFormat` to just be there.
>
> [Also] I created a cell for the output, and now reference that in `d3.select(events)` instead of `d3.select('#events')`. See [the little observer](https://beta.observablehq.com/@tmcw/the-little-observer) for one explanation of why: cells run the order that they need to depending on each other, so it’s best to connect things like `d3.select` to elements on the page based on referencing variables, rather than using strings like `‘#events’` to select elements on the page.